# Failed to load module script: Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: javascript, html, angular, localhost

Ive been stuck with this issue for the past 3 days. Ive tried looking into different threads but nothing seems to work for me.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Ive tried a couple of things but the issue im running into is with the type="module" in index.html. When I include it, I run into the error above, and when I remove it, I run into this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. Ive also attempted to change signup.js into signup.mjs. In the import statement, the path seems to be correct with firebase/app/dist/app being inside of node_modules. Ive also seen that the way im hosting might cause an issue. Currently, im using npm start with live-server. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my `scripts/signup.js`

```js
import { initializeApp } from "/../node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
// tokens
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

async function signup(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const username = document.getElementById('signupUsername').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('signupPassword').value;

    console.log(username, password, generateUUID())
}
```

My `index.html` is a bit long, so instead of spamming ill just add the script tag

```html
    <script src="scripts/signup.js" type="module"></script>
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "pool": "^0.4.1",
    "type":"module"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  }
}
```